# How can I add an ADFS user as User Profile Service Application Administrator?

Tags: user-profile-service, adfs

When I try to add an ADFS user to the 'Administrators for User Profile Service' list through Central Administration I get the error 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.  Parameter name: claim'.

[image: UPS Admin]

Trying to add via PowerShell via the following command gives the same error:

```
$serviceapp = Get-SPServiceApplication myApplicationId
$security = Get-SPServiceApplicationSecurity $serviceapp -Admin
$principalUser = New-SPClaimsPrincipal -Identity "i:0e.t|adfs|me@domain.com" -IdentityType EncodedClaim
Grant-SPObjectSecurity $security -Principal $principalUser -Rights "Full Control"
Set-SPServiceApplicationSecurity $serviceapp -ObjectSecurity $security -Admin
```

ULS logs the following error as well:
The claim 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn: me@domain.com' could not be added to the delegated administrators group because it does not represent a user or security group.

Also, when I try to give an ADFS user Connection Permissions to the User Profile Service through Central Administration, I get the error, "The User Profile Service Requires domain credentials for connection access":

[image: Connection Permissions]

How do you add ADFS users as User Profile Service Administrators?

Comment: Is your sharepoint configured to use users from ADFS?

Comment: On this link https://sharepointobservations.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/sharepoint-2013-how-to-install-and-configure-adfs-2-0/ on the second part about "Configure SharePoint Web Application" is guide how to configure everything correctly. Hope this helps.

Comment: SharePoint is configured to use ADFS.  My question is solely how to add ADFS users as User Profile Service Administrators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Windows (Domain) users can be added to Service Application security.

Comment: Given the scenario of an ADFS only deployment (other than Central Admin), how could an admin delete a Newsfeed post?

Comment: Well, given you need to have a Windows Claims enabled zone, in that case they would need to use that zone instead of their ADFS credentials.

Comment: By ADFS only, I meant that there is no available Windows Claim Zone.

Comment: Then Search won't function, which is typically important.